# Unwrap NewProxyConnection and GetConnection from NewProxyConnection

Tags: java, entitymanager, c3p0

I have the following structure:

1. A layer with Hibernate 4.0.1, using C3P0 as connection Pool.
2. I don't have datasources configured, I use a dynamic configuration of datasource like it:

   ```
   EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persitenceUnit", createMap(ds));
   ```

'ds' is a object with my database properties, like user, password, url, ...

1. I get Entitymanager this way:

   ```
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   ```
2. I try get connection this way:

   ```
   EntityManagerImpl entityManagerImpl = (EntityManagerImpl)em;
   SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl)entityManagerImpl.getSession().getSessionFactory();
   Connection con = sessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionProvider().getConnection();
   ```

But, con is a NewProxyConnection instance. I need execute a procedure that return an ORAData and `con.prepareCall(sqlToProcedure)` return a NewProxyCallableStatment that no have a getOraData, ie, this code don't work:

```
OracleCallableStatment ocs = (OracleCallableStatment)con.prepareCall('{call stp_test(?)}');   
ocs.excute();    
TestObjectodf to = ocs.getOraDATA(1, TestObject.getOraDataFactory());
```

The error happens in

```
OracleCallableStatment ocs = (OracleCallableStatment)con.prepareCall('{call stp_test(?)}');
```

I try:

```
NewProxyConnection npCon = sessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionProvider().getConnection();
Connection con = npCon.unwrap(Connection.class);
```

But don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unwrap() method will work, if you upgrade to the latest [c3p0-0.9.5 prerelease](https://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/files/c3p0-bin/c3p0-0.9.5-pre4/) version. unwrap() is a JDBC4 method, supported by c3p0 as of c3p0-0.9.5. Since you want an OracleCallableStatement, you will probably want to call the unwrap() method of a CallableStatement, rather than the unwrap() method of a Connection, as you try above.

Alternatively (and a bit more safely), with almost any version of the library, you can use c3p0's raw statement operations. [See the docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#raw_connection_ops).